# why mysql- Select data from table and display to php and when inserting it to another table in mysql it save only 1 value?

Tags: php, mysqli

When mysql- Select data from table and display to php and when inserting it to another table in mysql it save only 1 value.

Here are my code for select query :

```
<form method="GET" action="overtime_addconn.php">
if(!empty($_GET['search'])){
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_REQUEST['droplistsearch']);
$datefrom = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_REQUEST['datefrom']);
$dateto = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_REQUEST['dateto']); 

$sql="SELECT * 
FROM `overtime` 
where `empid`='$id' AND `dateofOT` BETWEEN '$datefrom' and '$dateto'";

$result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if($sql===FALSE) { die(mysql_error()); }

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
?>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="txdocno"  size="3px" id="txdocno"  value=" 
    <?php echo $row['docno'];?>" hidden></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="txchapa"  size="3px" id="txchapa"  value=" 
    <?php echo $row['empid'];?>" ></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="txEmpName" size="10px"id="txEmpName" 
    value="<?php echo $row['empname'];?>" ></td>
    <td><input type="date" name="txOTDate"  size="5px" id="txOTDate" value=" 
    <?php echo $row['dateofOT'];?>" ></td>
    <td><input type="time" name="txOTFrom"  size="5px" id="txOTFrom" value=" 
    <?php echo $row['overtimeFrom'];?>" ></td>
    <td><input type="time" name="txOTTo"  size="5px" id="txOTTo" value="<? 
    php echo $row['overttimeTo'];?>" ></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="txDesignation" size="5px"id="txDesignation" 
    value="<?php echo $row['worksched'];?>" ></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="txRemarks" size="30px"id="txRemarks" 
    value="<?php echo $row['justification'];?>" ></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Totalhrs"  size="10px" id="Totalhrs" 
    class="Totalhrs" value="<?php 
    $date = $row['dateofOT'];
    $From = $row['overtimeFrom'];
    $To =  $row['overttimeTo'];

    $starttime = new DateTime($date.''.$From);
    $endtime = new DateTime($date.''.$To);
    $diff = date_diff($starttime,$endtime);
    $totalhrs = $diff->h .'.'. $diff->i;
    echo $totalhrs;
    ?>" ></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="txStatus" value="<?php echo 
    $row['OTapproved'];?>"</td>
    </tr><?php }  }mysqli_close($conn); ?>
<input type="submit" name="OTsubmit" value="Submit" />
```

Then here are my code for Inserting:

```
ELSEIF(ISSET($_REQUEST['OTsubmit'])){
$txdocno = $_REQUEST['txdocno'];    
$txchapa = $_REQUEST['txchapa'];
$txEmpName = $_REQUEST['txEmpName'];
$txOTDate = $_REQUEST['txOTDate'];
$txOTFrom = $_REQUEST['txOTFrom'];
$txOTTo = $_REQUEST['txOTTo'];
$txDesignation = $_REQUEST['txDesignation'];
$txRemarks = $_REQUEST['txRemarks'];
$Totalhrs = $_REQUEST['Totalhrs'];
$txStatus = $_REQUEST['txStatus'];


 $sql1="INSERT INTO 
 `overtimemulti`(`rowno`,`chapano`,`employee`,`date`,`ottimein`,
`ottimeout`,`designation`,`remarks`,`ottotalhrs`,`status`) VALUES 
 ('$txdocno','$txchapa','$txEmpName','$txOTDate','$txOTFrom',
'$txOTTo','$txDesign
ation','$txRemarks','$Totalhrs','$txStatus')";
if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql1)){
echo "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>";
echo "alert('Successfuly Added!');";
echo "</script>";

$URL="overtimeMultiple.php";
echo "<script>location.href='$URL'</script>";

}
ELSE
{
echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($conn);
}
}
//Header("Location:overtime.php");
// close connection
mysqli_close($conn);
```

I'm wondering why is it only save 1 data instead of all data that I've selected or filtered in my parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the similar fields (e.g. `txdocno`) in your table have the same `name` attribute, so only one of them will be submitted with the form. You need to change them to have array style names:

```
    <td><input type="text" name="txdocno[]"  size="3px" id="txdocno"  value=" 
<?php echo $row['docno'];?>" hidden></td>
```

Note that you should really give them all unique `id` attributes as well, perhaps by using a row counter and using something like:

```
id="txdocno<?= $rowcount ?>"
```

If you make this change you will get arrays of data submitted to your insert code, so you will then need to loop on that to build the query. Note that you should use prepared statements to protect against injection so I've modified the code to do that:

```
$sql1="INSERT INTO `overtimemulti`
    (`rowno`, `chapano`, `employee`, `date`, `ottimein`, `ottimeout`, `designation`, `remarks`, `ottotalhrs`, `status`)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql1);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($txdocno); $i++) {
    $stmt->bind_param("ssssssssss", $txdocno[$i], $txchapa[$i], $txEmpName[$i], $txOTDate[$i], $txOTFrom[$i], $txOTTo[$i], $txDesignation[$i], $txRemarks[$i], $Totalhrs[$i], $txStatus[$i]);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

You will need to add the appropriate code to check the return status from the [`prepare()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) and [`execute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php) calls. Note that I have assumed all parameters are strings, if that is not the case, you will need to change the first parameter to [`bind_param()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) as required.

Comment: I'm newbie in PHP I'll try your suggestion sir. Thank you.

Comment: How about capturing the array name sir for Insert query? Can we do this?
$txdocno = $_REQUEST['txdocno[]'];

Comment: You don't need to do that, just use your existing code. PHP automatically sets `$_REQUEST['txdocno']` as the array of values with names `txdocno[]` in the HTML.

Comment: Sir? I encounter this error Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Only variables can be passed by reference in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\BISCOMHRMS\overtime_addconn.php:53 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\BISCOMHRMS\overtime_addconn.php on line 53

Comment: The one with bind_param sir. should i put [ ] for all my text field ? or the txdocno only?

Comment: All done sir .. THank you very much. I just add [ ] in all my textfield